# How can I retrieve Yngol's helm?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I tried to solve the puzzle to enter the last chamber in [Yngol's Tomb](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Helm_of_Yngol), but the door remain closed. I have the Coral Dragon Claw and the solution to the puzzle is printed on the claw.

Is this a known glitch? How do I enter the last chamber to retrieve Yngol's helm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is a known bug** which happens when you you have accepted the quest to find the Helm of Winterhold for the Jarl of Winterhold prior to entering Yngol Barrow.